# terminal in editor panel cannot be closed

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use (since 1.64) a command to open a terminal in an editor panel. The opening is (relatively) easy with `Create new terminal in editor area`. After some time working, possibly spawning additional jobs (e.g. `git gui &`) and closing them, I cannot close the terminal. In the tab is a black bullet and shows on hovering the `x` for closing, but cannot be activated.

What is the procedure to close the terminal in this situation?

Comment: Does Ctrl+W work to close it when that editor has focus?

Comment: no, this I tried....but I found the answer. see below

Answer (score 1):

The reasons why the terminal does not close is: some processes are still existing in the background - closed, not active, but still claiming resources. This is typically the reason, why I want to close the terminal, to force the release of these resources (e.g. ports), which new processes need.

The solution is to type `exit` in the terminal, which then either closes or prints a list of the still existing processes. A second `exit` then terminates these and the terminal closes as well.

I think this is a change in behavior compared to the "old" terminal. I am not sure if it is intentional or beneficial.